# is it possible to init FolderPicker with preferred folder

Tags: c#, uwp

my code to get the preset folder

```
StorageFolder aFolder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(encodeFolderString);
```

later, I hope to set the folder 'aFolder' as the initial folder of FolderPicker

```
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation=?????
```

Is it possible?

it looks like SuggestedStartLocation always relates to PickerLocationId and not for StorageFolder to set

Your comment welcome

Comment: Does the property *SuggestedStartLocation* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker?view=winrt-19041 help here?

Comment: OpenFileDialog is for win32, not for uwp

Comment: Oops! Sorry, overlooked this tag. Ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set a custom `SuggestedStartLocation` other than the ones listed in the [`PickerLocationId` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid?view=winrt-19041).

However it states in the documentation:

> The SuggestedStartLocation is not always used as the start location for the file picker. To give the user a sense of consistency, the file picker remembers the last location that the user navigated to and will generally start at that location.

This is by design of the pickers due to how UWP works.